# Laravel 5.6 - Error al ejecutar el comando php artisan migrate. Error con la llave foranea

Tags: php, laravel

cuando ejecuto el comando **php artisan migrate** para crear una tabla llamada  **articulos** me da error, pero si me crea la tabla  pero las llaves foráneas no funcionan ya que no se despliegan las categorías en el campo **idcategoria** de la tabla **artículos**,  tampoco se ven cambios en la tabla migrations.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**create_articulos_table.php**

```
Schema::create('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('codigo', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('nombre', 100)->unique();
            $table->decimal('precio_venta', 11, 2);
            $table->integer('stock');
            $table->string('descripcion', 256)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('condicion')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unsignedInteger('idcategoria');
            $table->foreign('idcategoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');

        });
```

**create_categorias_table.php**

```
Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre', 50);
            $table->string('descripcion', 256)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('condicion')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: el archivo de la migración de categorías esta antes que la de artículos?

Comment: si, en la carpeta migrations están, create_users_table.php, create_password_resets_table.php, create_categorias_table.php,create_articulos_table.php

Comment: Cuando declaras la llave foránea debería ser así: `$table->unsignedInteger('idcategoria')`

Comment: Checa en la documentación el apartado de `Foreign Key Constraint` [llaves foráneas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#indexes)

Comment: también puedes checar que el motor de ambas tablas sea tipo `InnoDB`

Comment: todos los campos son InnoDb, lo hice como en la documentación y sigue dando error

Comment: prueba 1. borrar manualmente la tabla creada con error (con phpmyadmin o instrucciones sql). 2. ejecuta `composer dump-autoload`. 3. luego vuelve a ejecutar `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ya intente eso y no funciona, elimine las tablas y lo hice de nuevo y el error es el mismo, puse antes y después el código de la llave foránea  y sigue dando el error.

Comment: sería bueno ver como es la columna 'id' de la tabla 'categorias'. Podrías postear también el código de la migración 'categorias'?. El mensaje de error es muy claro: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"...

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ya lo agrege

Comment: el código parece estar correcto. Solo se me ocurre recrear ambas tablas categorias y articulos

Comment: lo veo bien, puedes probar el comando `php artisan migrate:fresh` con las estructuras mostradas y decirnos que pasa?

Comment: Ya encontré la solución, desde HeidiSQL me di cuenta de que el campo id de la tabla categorías estaba como BIGINT y el campo idcategorias como INT, desde HeidiSQL cambie el campo de BINGINT a INT y agregue la llave foranea manualmente y funciono, después en el archivo de migración de  categorías cambie de $table->bigIncrements('id'); y lo deje solo así  $table->increments('id');  y funciono, Gracias por sus respuestas me ayudaron a dar con el problema. :D